# Canadian transit Visa

Tags: visas, canada

I applied for a Canadian transit visa online. I am  in Thailand and processing times say 16 days; today is the 19th day. What if it takes longer than the stated processing time indicated?

Comment: It happens all the time; sometimes the authorities just need more time to process your document due to your circumstances or the volume of applications they receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing times shown by the [Immigration and Citizenship Help Centre](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=070&top=3) are an average, based on the time it takes to approve or refuse 80 percent of applications. They offer a general idea of how long yours might take, not a guaranteed turnaround time.

> [How long will it take to process my application?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=031&top=3)
>   Processing times are difficult to predict. They vary depending on the type of application you submit and the number of applications currently being processed.
>
> [How are processing times calculated?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=068&top=3)
>   Citizenship and Immigration Canada (CIC) calculates processing times from the day CIC receives an application to the day it makes a decision on the application.
>
> When estimating how long you will wait to receive a temporary visa, you must also take into account up to 10 days of transit or delivery time on top of CIC’s processing time. The time your application will spend travelling to and from CIC will vary depending on where you live.

Comment: thank you very much so even if i apply online i still have to include the ten days ?

Comment: Yes, or more... ten days to get to Canada and ten days back, but the times are just a general range of what it MIGHT take. Unfortunately, you just have to wait until you get the decision.